# How to resolve .../AppDelegate.h:13:1: Duplicate interface definition for class 'AppDelegate' error

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I am following these instructions to integrate Appslflyer into my React-Native app: https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017822178#testing-ios-uninstalls

**WHAT AM I TRYING TO ACHIEVE**

I need to track iOS uninstalls. They use silent push notifications and require I copy-paste some code from the link above.

**WHAT IS MY PROBLEM?**

I've done all the other work to setup p12 certs and install but am getting stuck on merging the code from the instructions with existing code in my app.

**WHAT DID I TRY?**

I have no clue what I am looking at code-wise but I tried renaming AppDelegate to get past the duplicate interface name error in the .h file and imported it as AppDelegate2 but after that I don't have a clue how to implement the interface.

I also made an effort to paste some of the code into the existing implementation but still it wont build and tbh I don't know if it works even if it builds successfully.

Can someone with expertise in Objective-C assist? Thanks in advance.

I left the full content of AppDelegate in the code snippet in case you can spot where I can rather paste the new code to make life easier.

My AppDelegate.h looks like this BEFORE I follow the instructions:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <EXUpdates/EXUpdatesAppController.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <UMCore/UMAppDelegateWrapper.h>
#import <AppsFlyerLib/AppsFlyerLib.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UMAppDelegateWrapper <RCTBridgeDelegate, EXUpdatesAppControllerDelegate>

@end
```

and AFTER I follow the instructions it looks like:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <EXUpdates/EXUpdatesAppController.h>
    #import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    
    #import <UMCore/UMAppDelegateWrapper.h>
    #import <AppsFlyerLib/AppsFlyerLib.h>
    
    @interface AppDelegate : UMAppDelegateWrapper <RCTBridgeDelegate, EXUpdatesAppControllerDelegate>
    
    @end
    
    @interface AppDelegate2 : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, AppsFlyerLibDelegate>
    @end
```

My AppDelegate.m looks like this BEFORE I paste new code:

```
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "RNSailthruMobileBridge.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ReactNativeConfig.h"

#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <UMCore/UMModuleRegistry.h>
#import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMNativeModulesProxy.h>
#import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h>

#import <EXSplashScreen/EXSplashScreenService.h>
#import <UMCore/UMModuleRegistryProvider.h>
#import <RNAppsFlyer.h>

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>
#import <AppTrackingTransparency/AppTrackingTransparency.h>

#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>


static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif



@interface AppDelegate () <RCTBridgeDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UMModuleRegistryAdapter *moduleRegistryAdapter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *launchOptions;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  // Firebase
  if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
  }

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  self.moduleRegistryAdapter = [[UMModuleRegistryAdapter alloc] initWithModuleRegistryProvider:[[UMModuleRegistryProvider alloc] init]];

  self.launchOptions = launchOptions;
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

  #ifdef DEBUG
    [self initializeReactNativeApp];
  #else
    EXUpdatesAppController *controller = [EXUpdatesAppController sharedInstance];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [controller startAndShowLaunchScreen:self.window];
  #endif

  [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}

(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
       //NSString * token = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:deviceTokenencoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];
       NSLog(@"Device Token:%@",str);
       //NSLog(@"Device token is called");
       //const void *devTokenBytes = [deviceToken bytes];
       //NSLog(@"Device Token");
   }
   (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
       NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
       NSLog(@"Error:%@",str);
   }

(RCTBridge *)initializeReactNativeApp
{
//  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:self.launchOptions];
//  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil];

// then read individual keys like:
   NSString *SAIL_THRU_SDK_KEY = [ReactNativeConfig envFor:@"SAIL_THRU_SDK_KEY"];

  id<RCTBridgeDelegate> moduleInitialiser = [[RNSailthruMobileBridge alloc] initWithJSCodeLocation:[self sourceURLForBridge:nil] appKey:SAIL_THRU_SDK_KEY
 moduleRegistryAdapter: _moduleRegistryAdapter]; // Obtain SDK key from your Sailthru Mobile app settings

  RCTBridge * bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:moduleInitialiser launchOptions:self.launchOptions];

  RCTRootView * rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc]
                            initWithBridge:bridge
                            moduleName:@"main"
                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return bridge;
 }

(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *extraModules = [_moduleRegistryAdapter extraModulesForBridge:bridge];
  // If you'd like to export some custom RCTBridgeModules that are not Expo modules, add them here!
  return extraModules;
}

(NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
 #ifdef DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
 #else
  return [[EXUpdatesAppController sharedInstance] launchAssetUrl];
 #endif
}

(void)appController:(EXUpdatesAppController *)appController didStartWithSuccess:(BOOL)success {
  appController.bridge = [self initializeReactNativeApp];
  EXSplashScreenService *splashScreenService = (EXSplashScreenService *)[UMModuleRegistryProvider getSingletonModuleForClass:[EXSplashScreenService class]];
  [splashScreenService showSplashScreenFor:self.window.rootViewController];
}

(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
  [[AppsFlyerAttribution shared] continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
  [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                   continueUserActivity:userActivity
                     restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
  return YES;
}

(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}

(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary *) options {
    [[AppsFlyerAttribution shared] handleOpenUrl:url options:options];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

... and like this AFTER I paste new code:

```
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "RNSailthruMobileBridge.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ReactNativeConfig.h"

#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <UMCore/UMModuleRegistry.h>
#import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMNativeModulesProxy.h>
#import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h>

#import <EXSplashScreen/EXSplashScreenService.h>
#import <UMCore/UMModuleRegistryProvider.h>
#import <RNAppsFlyer.h>

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>
#import <AppTrackingTransparency/AppTrackingTransparency.h>

#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>


static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@interface AppDelegate2 () <UIApplicationDelegate>
@end

@interface AppDelegate () <RCTBridgeDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UMModuleRegistryAdapter *moduleRegistryAdapter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *launchOptions;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
      ########## below is new code from AppsFlyer instructions #########
// The userNotificationTypes below is just an example and may be changed depending on the app
   UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
            center.delegate = self;
            [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            }];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
      // if you do not use push notificaiton in your app, uncomment the following line
      //application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }
  ########## above is new code from AppsFlyer instructions #########
  
  // Firebase
  if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
  }

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  self.moduleRegistryAdapter = [[UMModuleRegistryAdapter alloc] initWithModuleRegistryProvider:[[UMModuleRegistryProvider alloc] init]];

  self.launchOptions = launchOptions;
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

  #ifdef DEBUG
    [self initializeReactNativeApp];
  #else
    EXUpdatesAppController *controller = [EXUpdatesAppController sharedInstance];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [controller startAndShowLaunchScreen:self.window];
  #endif

  [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}

(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
       //NSString * token = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:deviceTokenencoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];
       NSLog(@"Device Token:%@",str);
       //NSLog(@"Device token is called");
       //const void *devTokenBytes = [deviceToken bytes];
       //NSLog(@"Device Token");
   }
   (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
       NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
       NSLog(@"Error:%@",str);
   }

(RCTBridge *)initializeReactNativeApp
{
//  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:self.launchOptions];
//  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil];

// then read individual keys like:
   NSString *SAIL_THRU_SDK_KEY = [ReactNativeConfig envFor:@"SAIL_THRU_SDK_KEY"];

  id<RCTBridgeDelegate> moduleInitialiser = [[RNSailthruMobileBridge alloc] initWithJSCodeLocation:[self sourceURLForBridge:nil] appKey:SAIL_THRU_SDK_KEY
 moduleRegistryAdapter: _moduleRegistryAdapter]; // Obtain SDK key from your Sailthru Mobile app settings

  RCTBridge * bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:moduleInitialiser launchOptions:self.launchOptions];

  RCTRootView * rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc]
                            initWithBridge:bridge
                            moduleName:@"main"
                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return bridge;
 }

(NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *extraModules = [_moduleRegistryAdapter extraModulesForBridge:bridge];
  // If you'd like to export some custom RCTBridgeModules that are not Expo modules, add them here!
  return extraModules;
}

(NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
 #ifdef DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
 #else
  return [[EXUpdatesAppController sharedInstance] launchAssetUrl];
 #endif
}

(void)appController:(EXUpdatesAppController *)appController didStartWithSuccess:(BOOL)success {
  appController.bridge = [self initializeReactNativeApp];
  EXSplashScreenService *splashScreenService = (EXSplashScreenService *)[UMModuleRegistryProvider getSingletonModuleForClass:[EXSplashScreenService class]];
  [splashScreenService showSplashScreenFor:self.window.rootViewController];
}

(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
  [[AppsFlyerAttribution shared] continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
  [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                   continueUserActivity:userActivity
                     restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
  return YES;
}

(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url
                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}

(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary *) options {
    [[AppsFlyerAttribution shared] handleOpenUrl:url options:options];
    return YES;
}
########## below is new code from AppsFlyer instructions #########
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
  [[AppsFlyerLib shared] registerUninstall:deviceToken];
}

@end
```

I get this error when I build:
[Screenshot of the error in Xcode: .../AppDelegate.h:13:1: Duplicate interface definition for class 'AppDelegate'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB9hV.jpg)

Comment: `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` your new code have 2 methods same implementation. remove one and run.

Comment: Thanks, that was a copy-pasting mistake. I've fixed the mistake. How do I implement that AppDelegate2 in .m file, for the interface in the .h file? Would that resolve?

Comment: generally `AppDelegate` work as entry point of an app. so i think entry point can't be duplicate.

Comment: why do you want second `AppDelegate`. can you describe.

Comment: My problem is that the instructions from Appsflyer require me to paste code that introduces a new AppDelegate interface meaning I end up with two of them in my AppDelegate.h file. If I can only have 1 interface what should I do with this:

`@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, AppsFlyerLibDelegate>
    @end`

since it has a different signature to the one already in AppDelegate.h?

Comment: yeah i got your point i am sure that `AppsFlyerLibDelegate` you will get from any framwork. Right?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but the appsflyer library requires that I paste this:

`@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, AppsFlyerLibDelegate>     @end`

 into AppDelagate.h, but that file already has this:

`@interface AppDelegate : UMAppDelegateWrapper <RCTBridgeDelegate, EXUpdatesAppControllerDelegate>

@end`

How do I get them to work together?